# Permissions for Wordpress on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: server, apache2, wordpress

On my web server - runnnig LAMP - I have a Wordpress installation, where I'd like to set the ownerships/permissions like this:

my-username is the owner of all files while the owner group is www-data (`chown -R my-username:www-data`). I've set `chmod -R 775` on whole installation folder, so users in owner group should be able to write the files/folders. For some reason Wordpress can't write them, the only configuration when it works is when www-data is owner user (`chown -R www-data:www-data`).

The problem with that, is that I use Gulp to compile my assets, and Gulp can only run if the owner of the files it needs to write, is the user who runs Gulp from the command-line (my-username in this case). I've also tried setting `chown -R www-data:www-data` and include my-username in www-data group, so that my-username running Gulp would have write permissions (I can write files in the terminal), but Gulp would not work.

How should I set this up, so that both Wordpress(www-data) and Gulp(my-username) could have working write-permissions? Why is having group-permissions not enough?